# Outputting irish language characters (cmd.exe) from c#

Tags: c#, cmd, diacritics, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to create a command line program capable of outputting different languages.

Is there a way to set the encoding for outputting to the command line through Console.WriteLine?

I want to swap between utf-8 and shift-JIS and not assume the command shell program is in the right format.

Just to add more information about this. My current code reads in a file which has special characters:

```
"Fadó, fadó"
```

but the output doesn't properly display the special characters:

```
"Fado, fado"
```

I am simply using Console.WriteLine:

```
foreach (string s in lines)
{
     Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

I have not figure out how to set the encoding for Console.WriteLine.  Is it even possible, or is there an alternative that someone can point out?

Comment: Sounds like the [Console.OutputEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.outputencoding.aspx) property may be what you want.

Comment: First thing to do is check whether the problem is reading or writing. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx for some code to help you debug this sort of thing.

Comment: Reading is fine as it outputs fine to text file. Its just the console output. It looks like Console.OutputEncoding is the answer alright.

Comment: Fairy tales on the command line? That's cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need to use `Unicode`encoding.

```
string[] lines = new[] { "Fadó", "fadó" };
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

foreach (string s in lines) { Console.WriteLine(s); }
```